# How Can I Create Multiple Checkboxes That Stay Either Checked or Unchecked on Browser Refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

How can I create multiple checkboxes **that either stay checked or unchecked on browser refresh depending on what I choose using JavaScript?** I figured out how to do one checkbox, but when I tried to add another checkbox the initial checkbox wouldn't remember that it had been checked on the refresh (if that makes sense lol). Please help. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div id="checkbox-container">
                <input type="checkbox" id="name"/>
            </div> 
        </div>
    <script>
        var checkboxValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValue')) || {}
        var $checkbox = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");
    
        $checkbox.on("change", function() {
            $checkbox.each(function() {
                checkboxValue[this.id] = this.checked;
            });
            localStorage.setItem("checkboxValue", JSON.stringify(checkboxValue));
        });
    
        //on page load
        $.each(checkboxValue, function(key, value) {
            $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .wrap input {
            position: absolute;
            top: 300px;
            left: 500px;
        }
  
        input[type=checkbox] {
            transform: scale(2);
            margin: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    
        .wrap { 
            filter: hue-rotate(410deg); 
        }
    </style>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only storing one value in the localStorage.

```
localStorage.setItem("checkboxValue", JSON.stringify(checkboxValue));
```

Any time a checkbox value changes, you store that one value. I'd recommend setting an ID, name or data-value that distinguishes your checkboxes from each other. Then use that as the key in the local storage.

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //on page load
    $(document).ready(function(){
        populateCheckBoxes();
        $("#checkbox-container :checkbox").on("change", function() {
            // use this.id as the key for local storage
            localStorage.setItem(this.id, JSON.stringify(this.checked));
        });
    });
    function populateCheckBoxes() {
        $("#checkbox-container :checkbox").each(function() {
            // get just the localStorage for this checkbox by this.id
            const value = localStorage.getItem(this.id) || false;
            // value is stored as a string, so need to check for a boolean
            this.checked = value == 'true';
        });
        
    }
</script>
<style>
input[type=checkbox] {
    transform: scale(2);
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.wrap { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 500px;
  filter: hue-rotate(410deg); 
}
</style>
<body>
<!-- html should go between the <body> and </body> tags -->
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="checkbox-container">
        <!-- set different ids for each checkbox -->
        <!-- ids must be unique over the whole document -->
        <input type="checkbox" id="is-human"/><label for="is-human">Is Human</label>
        <br><input type="checkbox" id="is-adult"/><label for="is-adult">Is Adult</label>
    </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So how do I add two values instead of one?

Comment: @NicholasDavies I have edited my answer to provide a working sample. Basically, give each checkbox an id then use the id as the key when writing to or reading from localStorage.

Comment: Thanks so much bro! I'm not super familiar with javascript so that helped me out a lot :)